# How to add comments into a mustache template?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

In my Mustache template, I would like to comment a couple of lines, but I am unable to do it. I am still getting the comments displayed in HTML. What is the correct way to add comments? Anyone can help me to sort this out please?

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="inspector-splitViewBase">
    <div class="inspector-split-view-container flex-1 flex-fill flex-down">
        <header class='split-view-inspector-header'>
            <div class="view-title">Source Assets</div>
            {{!--  <div class="actions"> commented 
                <span class="label">Actions</span>
                <span class="gear"></span>
            </div> --}} - comment is not working
        </header>
        <div class='search-container'>
            <span class="search-icon"></span>
            <input type="text" value="" class="inspector-search" />
        </div>
        <div class="source-assets-list-container flex-1"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting each line with {{! }} instead of a multiline comment?

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: You can comment the entire HTML element and it will not show up(using `<!--` `-->`)

Comment: This works perfectly for me using your example. Could the template be cached?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mustache [documentation](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) suggests to use following for comments:

```
Comments begin with a bang and are ignored. The following template:
    <h1>Today{{! ignore me }}.</h1>

Will render as follows:    
    <h1>Today.</h1>

Comments may contain newlines.
```

I assume that in your case you had to use

```
{{! blah }}
```

Instead of

```
{{!--  blah --}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to comment on mustache template that also has html in it, so you actually have to add mustache comment where the mustache code is and html comment where the html code is.

.